# iphone: how to do Page turning

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, quartz-graphics, caanimation

I am facing the problem from a month and didn't find anything from google..

I am using UIView for pdf display. there is no problem with pdf but problem is with transition. I have to turn each page of pdf with realistic page turn exp. I search, dig a lot about that but i didn't get anything that how to do that.

I don't want to use any API'S like codeflake or any other. all i want to do this by my own programming.

First i read that this can be done using cocos2d or CAAnimation but i want to know how? b'coz realistic page i think so is completely 3d concept.

Let me know guys how to do thay??

here's the example video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oknMWvRO2XE

I want animation just like in video....

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few open source examples of iOS page curl/flip effect:

https://github.com/brow/leaves - Simple effect using CAGradientLayers. (All public API calls)

https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/PageCurlDemo - Uses CAFilter (The same method used in iBooks, but this is a private API call and Apple WILL reject your app if you use it). What might be useful here is the code for calculating the angle of touch, which could be used to improve the Leaves example.

Answer (score 0):

The LeavesView component gets my vote, I'm using it in a commercial interactive book application. If you check out the forks on GitHub, there are some other neat patches which you may choose to integrate.

Its pretty simple to integrate and includes a few examples, including a PDF rendering one. You can also add interactive layers on top if you wish, which is what I do.

Comment: How do you add interactive layers? The leaves project on GitHub specifically says it doesn't support interactive layers.